# Testing StencilJS React components with Jest + React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, stenciljs

Has anyone had any luck configuring React Testing Library for testing StencilJS React wrapped components?

I'm getting this error when running the tests:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')

      31 |
      32 |   const displayName = dashToPascalCase(tagName);
    > 33 |   const ReactComponent = class extends React.Component<StencilReactInternalProps<ElementType>> {
         |                                              ^
      34 |     componentEl!: ElementType;
      35 |
      36 |     setComponentElRef = (element: ElementType) => {
```

I guess it's got something to do with calling defineCustomElements correctly:

```
import { defineCustomElements } from '@salable/stencil-library/loader';

defineCustomElements(window);
```

I have tried adding it to jest setup scripts, beforeAll and in the top of the test file.

This is my current test file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import {MyComponent} from "../lib";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

import { defineCustomElements } from '@salable/stencil-library/loader';

defineCustomElements(window);

test('component loads and renders', async () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(screen.getByText(/hello/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': ['ts-jest', {
            tsconfig: 'tsconfig.test.json',
        }],
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/dist/'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom', '<rootDir>/__tests__/jest.setup.ts'],
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    clearMocks: true,
};
```

Comment: I can surmise the issue is with the use of custom elements. have you tried setting up a different custom elements jest setup file and adding it to your jest's `setupFilesAfterEnv` property?

Comment: @mandy8055 I've tried calling this `defineCustomElements(window)` in setupFilesAfterEnv. This `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom', '<rootDir>/__tests__/jest.setup.ts'],` is in the `jest.config.js`. I added a console.log in the to ensure it's hitting the file.